# Ошибка при вызове функций из $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific, slick.js

На сайте используются плагины [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) и [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). При вызове функций с их использованием следующим образом:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initPopupsFromComBlock();
    runBrandsSlick();
    //some other code.....
});
```

Получаю в консоле ошибку - TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function. Однако, если вынести вызов этих функций за пределы $(document).ready,

```
initPopupsFromComBlock();
runBrandsSlick();
```

то все работает нормально. initPopupsFromComBlock() находится за пределами $(document).ready.

```
function initPopupsFromComBlock() {
    $('.fast-order').magnificPopup({
        .......
    });
}
```

Последовательность подключения скриптов:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('slick/slick.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myscript.js" ></script>
```

П.С.: Такую же ошибку выдает и в случае, если код из вызываемой функции полностью поместь во внутрь $(document).ready. В чем прикол?

П.П.С: Далее подобная проблема возникает при вызове функции, в которой используется Magnific Popup, из другой функции.

```
function getCurrency() {
$.ajax({
    url: "/modules/content/ajax/get_currency.php",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'HTML'})
        .done(function (data) {
            if (data) {
                $('.top-popups .currency-wrap .d-table a').remove();
                $('.top-popups .currency-wrap .d-table').append(data);
            } else {
                magnificPopupOpenError('Во время загрузки валюты произошла ошибка!');
            }
        }).fail(function () {
    magnificPopupOpenError('Сервер не отвечает!');
});
```

}

Функция magnificPopupOpenError:

```
function magnificPopupOpenError(text) {
$.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {
        src: '<div id="white-popup"><div class="custom-border-tooltip">' + text + '</div></div>',
        type: 'inline'
    }
});
```

}

Ошибка: TypeError: $.magnificPopup is undefined

Comment: попробуй каждому тегу script добавить атрибут defer (http://htmlbook.ru/html/script/defer)

Comment: @MishaSaidov Так перестало работать и за пределами $(document).ready

Comment: Покажите весь код в document.ready

Comment: @ЕгорЖолнин Почти 2к строчек кода - не помещается сюда...

Comment: @IhorAllin Хотя бы то, что внутри  этих двух функций. И можно на какой-нибудь jsfiddle

Comment: @ЕгорЖолнин внутренности $(document).ready https://jsfiddle.net/Igorallin/vdf9bLz6/

Comment: @ЕгорЖолнин функции - https://jsfiddle.net/Igorallin/gpv37uhe/

Comment: @IhorAllin А в исходниках плагинов нет одинаковых функций, которые могут конфликтовать? У меня такая история была с Fancybox и Arcticmodal